# How to approach unit testing in a large project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

We have a project that is starting to get large, and we need to start applying Unit Tests as we start to refactor. What is the best way to apply unit tests to a project that already exists? I'm (somewhat) used to doing it from the ground up, where I write the tests in conjunction with the first lines of code onward. I'm not sure how to start when the functionality is already in place. Should I just start writing test for each method from the repository up? Or should I start from the Controllers down?

**update:**
to clarify on the size of the project.. I'm not really sure how to describe this other than to say there's 8 Controllers and about 167 files that have a .cs extension, all done over about 7 developer months..

Comment: How large are you talking, I believe it is relevant?

Comment: 10 developer months of development.. at a mediocre development level (if that makes sense)

Comment: How many classes, pages?

Comment: @Keiren, i miscalculated - it's about 7 developer months

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you seem to be aware, retrofitting testing into an existing project is not easy.  Your method of writing tests as you go is the better way.  Your problem is one of both process and technology- tests must be required by everyone or no one will use them.

The recommendation I've heard and agree with is that you should not attempt to wrap tests around an existing codebase all at once.  You'll never finish.  Start by working testing into your bugfix process- every fixed bug gets a test.  This will start to work testing into your existing code over time.  New code must *always* have tests, of course.  Eventually, you'll get the coverage up to a reasonable percentage, but it will take time.

One good book I've had recommended to me is [*Working Effectively With Legacy Code*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052) by Michael C. Feathers.  The title doesn't really demonstrate it, but working testing into an existing codebase is a major subject of the book.

Comment: It is in fact the foundation of the book, as his definition of Legacy Code is Code Without Tests.

Comment: +1, I have just finished reading it, it's a great book! (Oh and the +1 is for the good summary).

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of approaches to fitting tests around an existing codebase.  Unit tests are not necessarily the most productive way to start.  If you have a large amount of code written then you might want to think about functional and integration tests before you work down to the level of unit tests.  Those higher level tests will help give you broad assurance that your product continues to work while you make changes to improve the structure and retrofit unit tests.

One of the practices that non-test-first organizations use that I recommend highly in your situation is this:  Have someone other than the author of the original code section write the unit tests for that section.  This gets you some level of cross-training and sanity checking, and it also helps ensure that you don't preserve assumptions which will do damage to your code overall.

Other than that, I'll second the recommendation for Michael Feathers' book.

Answer (score 0):

For a legacy project with a decently sized code base, unit testing everything may not be a justifiable effort spend due to budgetary constraints etc. Based on my reading on this subject, I would suggest:

1. Every bug which has been leaked to QA, Release or Production environment is a candidate for writing unit test case(s) along with fixing the bug.
2. Use source control to find out which sections/files of your code base are changing more frequently than others. Bring those sections/files under unit test coverage.
3. New story development should have meaningful unit test case written against them.
4. Keep monitoring the unit test coverage to observe any downward trend in particular area of the code base. This area needs you to zoom-in and review if unit test coverage is loosing its effectiveness or not.

P.S.: I have added Michael Feathers book to my reading list, thanks for suggesting it.